# How to show multiple values in display item oracle forms?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am creating calculator on forms developer 11g

I want to show multiple values in one display item Like 1 + 1

I have multiple buttons like 1,2,3... and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed earlier, use concatenation; every button would have its own `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger and do

```
-- WBP on digit '1' button
:block.item := :block.item || '1';

-- WBP on digit '2' button
:block.item := :block.item || '2';

--WBP on the "+" sign button
:block.item := :block.item ||'+';
```

and so on.